# Real Periodic Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose we have some input data (only real numbers) and the data is periodic. Is it true that the Fourier coefficients will also be only real numbers?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question more. Fourier transforms are usually defined for integrable (or square integrable) signals. Are you asking about Fourier series maybe?

Comment: Or are you asking about the discrete fourier transform?

Answer (score 2):

If your input is an analog signal $t\mapsto f(t)\in{\mathbb R}$ of period $T>0$ then you can expand it into a  Fourier series of the form
$$f(t)={a_0\over2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(a_k\cos{2k\pi t\over T}+b_k\sin{2k\pi t\over T}\right)$$
with *real* coefficients $a_k$, $b_k$.

When the input data represent a discrete signal $k\mapsto y_k\in{\mathbb R}$ $\>(k\in{\mathbb Z})$ of period $N$ then the so-called discrete Fourier transform, which works with the complex exponential function, produces *complex* Fourier coefficients $c_j$ $\>(0\leq j<N)$. The fact that the $y_k$ are real is then reflected in the "symmetry" $c_{-j}\bigl(=c_{N-j}\bigr)=\overline{c_j}$.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is definitely not true! You can try to check the fourier transform of the sequence {1 2}

Answer (score 0):

No. For example if you want to do the Fourier transform of

$$
f : \mathbb R \to [0,1]: t \to \sin(\omega t )
$$

Than we get using the Euler formula

$$
\frac{1}{\omega}  \int_{0}^{\omega} \sin(\omega t ) \exp(i \omega k t ) dt= \frac{1}{\omega} \int_{0}^{\omega} \sin(\omega t ) \cos (\omega k t )dt + i\frac{1}{\omega} \int_{0}^{\omega} \sin(\omega t ) \sin (\omega k t ) dt
$$

The first integral will clearly be $0$ due to symmetry, and the second coefficient will be one only be different from $0$ if $k=1$. Hope this helps a bit.